# How to insert data in SQL Server with pymssql?

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I am trying to insert data into a table in SQL Server via Python code using pymssql.

my table was created as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE test(
                col1 VARCHAR(100),
                col2 DECIMAL(5,2) 
              );
```

My Python code:

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(host = server,user = user,password = password,database = database)
cur = conn.cursor()

a = ["apple","orange"]
b = [5.2,6.4]
data = [(a[i],b[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO test(col1,col2) VALUES (?,?)', data)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

But I get the following error:

```
pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near '?'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Try `%s` instead of `?`

Comment: THank you @Justin Ezequiel,  it worked for me.